# Custom renderer for PrimeFaces component works fine in Tomcat, but not in Websphere

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere, myfaces, custom-renderer

I'm using MyFaces 2.1.9 and PrimeFaces 3.5. I've implemented a custom renderer for `<p:inputText>`. This works fine at home with Tomcat. But this does not work at work with Websphere. I've placed breakpoints in the custom renderer class, but they are never hit. I see nothing in my logs as well. However, when I register the very same custom renderer on standard JSF `<h:inputText>`, then it works fine.

I've registered it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<render-kit>
    <renderer>
        <component-family>org.primefaces.component</component-family>
        <renderer-type>org.primefaces.component.InputTextRenderer</renderer-type>
        <renderer-class>xxx.xxx.xxx.MyInputRenderer</renderer-class>
    </renderer>
</render-kit>
```

How can I troubleshoot the registration of the custom renderer?

Comment: Start with a breakpoint on `RenderKit#addRenderer()`.

Comment: Thanks! Now I know that my renderer is processed first, then the regular renderer comes along in addREnderer and overwrites mine! How can I solve this?

Comment: Okay, that indeed explains it. Where's your `faces-config.xml`? In a custom module JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` or directly in webapp's `/WEB-INF`? If in JAR, then the loading order is undefined. If it's loaded before the PrimeFaces one, then you get this problem.

Comment: It's in my regular web module. Here's my location: /WEB-INF/spring/faces-config.xml. I point to that URL with the javax.faces.CONFIG_FILES context parameter.

Comment: Try declaring it directly in main `/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml`.

Comment: Now it works! I wonder why though...

Comment: Do you want to create an answer so you can get the points? Otherwise I'll do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Custom renderers which needs to override renderers of 3rd party component libraries needs to be registered in webapp's own `faces-config.xml`, not in a `faces-config.xml` which is packed in another JAR in `/WEB-INF/lib` as well. The loading order of JAR files is unspecified, so it may happen that the custom renderer is loaded and registered *before* the one of the 3rd party component library which you'd like to override, exactly like as you faced.