# JSF 2.0 and Weblogic 11 - Include faces-config specifications in referenced library

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, weblogic11g, faces-config

I am trying to decouple application-layer code from view layer html, css, js in a JSF 2.0 web application.

The view layer of the application will be a deployed WAR file with the standard structure.

The java code will be in a Weblogic deployed library (referenced by the war in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml). This will contain only the class files as well as many required jars.

I don't want the people working on the view layer to have direct connection to the application layer. Can I include specifications normally from the faces-config.xml of the application inside the referenced library's faces-config.xml instead? These include: exception-handler-factory, resource bundle references, el-resolvers, listeners, render-kit, etc.

```
Application Structure
    -App-Layer Library
        -META-INF
            -faces-config.xml???
        -WEB-INF
            -classes
            -lib (jars here)
            -web.xml
    -View-Layer Application
        -META-INF
        -WEB-INF
            -faces-config.xml
            -web.xml
            -weblogic.xml
            -weblogic-application.xml
         -Other folders
```

Sorry if this is not clear enough, my first question on Stack Overflow! Please feel free to let me know if I can clarify anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You can have an app library for commons, configuration and java code separate of the view-layer. In this jar (library) you put all that you need at the JSF config file, (`faces-config.xml`) located in `src/META-INF/faces-config.xml`.  In my case i have  exception-handler-factory, resource bundle references, el-resolvers, listeners in this config file, and don't have any problem in weblogic.

But, there are some issues to take in mind. For example, override a 3rd part, renderer or component.

> [Custom renderers which needs to override renderers of 3rd party
>   component libraries needs to be registered in webapp's own
>   faces-config.xml, not in a faces-config.xml which is packed in another
>   JAR in /WEB-INF/lib as well. The loading order of JAR files is
>   unspecified, so it may happen that the custom renderer is loaded and
>   registered before the one of the 3rd party component library which
>   you'd like to override, exactly like as you faced.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15919624/custom-renderer-for-primefaces-component-works-fine-in-tomcat-but-not-in-websph)

I hope, that resolve some of yours doubts...